# Practical advantage of using polymorphism over inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

What is the advantage of using polymorphism in C++ over using mere inheritance, as it seems to me that i can't achieve with polymorphism something what I can't do with mere inheritance. Also in both ways i can make use of virtual functions. Is there a situation where polymorphism can do something which is not reachable by using mere inheritance?

These 2 exemples (first - polymorphism, second - mere inheritance) allowed me to reach the same results, so im wondering what else can polympthism provide me with, which cannot be achieved by doing by normal inheritance.

Polymorphism code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Kryptonians
{
public:
    void setPower(int p) {power = p;}
    void gotHit(int h){power -=h;}
    virtual void displayPower(){std::cout << "power is: " << power << "\n";}

protected:
    int power;
};

class Supergirl: public Kryptonians
{
public:
   void displayPower(){
       std::cout << "Supergirl's power is: " << power << "\n";}
};

class Superman: public Kryptonians
{
public:
    void displayPower(){
        std::cout << "Superman's power is: " << power << "\n";}
};

int main()
{
    Supergirl sup;
    Superman super;
    Kryptonians *supergirl = &sup;
    Kryptonians *superman = &super;

    supergirl->setPower(100);
    supergirl->displayPower();

    superman->setPower(100);
    superman->gotHit(50);
    superman->displayPower();
    supergirl->displayPower();
}
```

Mere inhetirance code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Kryptonians
{
public:
    void setPower(int p) {power = p;}
    void gotHit(int h){power -=h;}
    virtual void displayPower(){std::cout << "power is: " << power << "\n";}

    protected:
    int power;
};

class Supergirl: public Kryptonians
{
public:
    void displayPower(){
        std::cout << "Supergirl's power is: " << power << "\n";}
};

class Superman: public Kryptonians
{
public:
    void displayPower(){
        std::cout << "Superman's power is: " << power << "\n";}
};

int main()
{
    Supergirl supergirl;
    supergirl.setPower(100);
    supergirl.displayPower();

    Superman superman;
    superman.setPower(100);
    superman.gotHit(50);
    superman.displayPower();

    supergirl.displayPower();
}
```

My question is about why to use polymorphism at all, when one could do pretty well avoid using it, and limiting themselves to only use inheritance. As user463035818 stated, basicly there is  no situation where polymorphism can do something which is not reachable by using inheritance. So as i understand, using polymprphism is the prefered design patter?

Comment: Dynamic polymorphism is achieved through inheritance. I don't understand the question.

Comment: It would be easier if you showed us two solutions to a same problem, one using (what you call) polymorphism, and one using (what you call) inheritance.

Comment: Please provide an example snippet for each situation, then we can understand better the two situations you want to compare. (to me, they're the same)

Comment: Do you mean [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)? No. Clearly not on re-read. I join the others in puzzlement.

Comment: I know that polymorhism is achieved through inheritance. However I ask what more I can do with polymorphism what is impossible through mere inheritance.

Comment: Only think I can think of is you can take full advantage of the [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) between derived class and base class, allowing the derived class to fully masquerade as a base class.

Comment: These 2 exemples (first - inheritance, second - polymorphism) allowed me to reach the same results, so im wondering what else can polympthism provide me with, which cannot be achieved by doing by normal inheritance.

Normal inheritance code:
https://pastebin.com/HtNLZ2B2

Polymorphism code:
https://pastebin.com/L6Vjkn7v

Comment: @memphis Your two snippets do different things, e.g. polymorphism-less one doesn't have customized messages for derived classes. Also, make sure to include code snippets *in the question itself*. It's customary and saves us clicks.

Answer (score 2):

At least in C++, the primary reason to use inheritance is for polymorphism. There is also something called "implementation inheritance", but it's frowned upon as a general rule.

The canonical example of polymorphism would involve a virtual function, which is declared in a base class and implemented in a derived class:

```
class interface { 
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class implementation : public interface { 
public:
    virtual void foo() override {
        // do something useful here
    }
};
```

In this case, the base class doesn't actually implement `foo` at all, it just declares an interface, so that any code that works with that interface can work with any derivative of that base class.

Implementation inheritance is primarily for cases where you have a number of derived classes that all do slight variations on the same general things, so you can implement the common behavior in the case class, and each derived class only implements the areas in which it varies from that common base.

One fairly well known example of implementation inheritance in C++ is `std::iterator`. This is a base class that contains on virtual functions (so no polymorphism). It's sole purpose is to provide some `typedef`s that iterators are expected to provide. The types are all typically related, so a derived class can typically pass a single template parameter to the base class, and get all the necessary `typedef`s:

```
class my_iterator : public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void> {
    // ...
};
```

This saves the implementer of the iterator from typing code like this:
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptr_diff_t;
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using pointer = T*;

It does save some typing--but not a whole lot, and what it saves is almost all simple boiler-plate anyway.

As mentioned above, however, this is frowned upon as a rule--in fact, `std::iterator` is officially deprecated, so it may disappear from some future version of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

**Polymorphism**

> In computer science, polymorphism is a programming language feature
>   that allows values of different data types to be handled in a uniform
>   manner.

For example:

```
void foo(bar& b) {
   b.do_something();
};
```

Treating objects of different types the same is called polymorphism. `b` can be of any type as long as it inherits `bar`.

**Inheritance**

> Inheritance is the system in object oriented programming that allows
>   objects to support operations defined by anterior types without having
>   to provide their own definition. It is the major vector for
>   polymorphism in object-oriented programming

For example:

```
struct bar {
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
    virtual ~bar(){}
};

struct foobar1 : bar {
    virtual void do_something() override {
        std::cout << "muh";
    }
};

struct foobar2 : bar {
    virtual void do_something() override {
        std::cout << "meh";
    }
};
```

Different types can inherit the same base class such that they can be used polymorphically.

> Is there a situation where polymorphism can do something which is not
>   reachable by using inheritance?

No.

Well....Yes.

Some usage of tempaltes can be considered as compile time polymorphism. If you are interested in compile time polymorpishm you should take a look at the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)